# meta http equiv refresh does not work properly in ff and ie when the url has a get param

Tags: http, refresh, meta

I am trying to redirect the user after he posts some data to the url below.

I am using this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=/homepage/?show=ads" />
```

It works in Chrome, Opera, Safari.

Not in FF and IE.

What I mean is the user is redirected in all the above mentioned browsers, but FF and IE don't take into account the show='ads' variable, which should display a completely different page than /homepage/

I can work around this and redirect the user to a different url without any get params, but I was curious why is this happening in FF and IE.

Anyone has an explanation for it?

Comment: Works fine for me. Try hitting `ctrl`+`F5` to force the browser to reload the content - you may be working from a cached version. Also try simply restarting them.

Comment: i tried ctrl + f5, shift + f5, restarting the browser and even <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> in the html.. nothing worked .. ff 9.0.1 and ie 9.0.8 .. thanks for trying though

Comment: The problem was that I was using the http referer in my code which was rendering /homepage/?show=ads and from what I saw FF and IE does not keep the referer after the refresh.

It was in a try except KeyError block and it was failing silently.

Comment: Also beware that using a , instead of a ; works on Chrome, but not on IE...